# Render combination of html,Javascripts and css to an UI(View) in MVC using JQuery dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am tying to render the dynamic html,javascripts(both references and scripts) and css(both references and style link) in a controll of a view using jquery. But the javascripts are not rendering properly any one give me the right approach for this. In addition I am using ajax get request and get the content details in a single property.

here are my code

```
$.ajax({
    url: postURL,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestBody),

    success: function (data) {
        var control = $('#channelPartner');
        control.html(data.DivContent);
        //$("head").append(data.HeaderContent.replace(/"/g, "'"));
        control.attr("data-token", data.Token);
        control.attr("data-partner", data.PartnerName);

        setTimeout(function () {
            volly();
        }, 10);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: `I am using ajax get request...`. We can't see your code.

Comment: I haven't add before :(

Comment: @SivaRajagopal u need to get text from other html file

Comment: @Selva No the intense is I need to get the result as a string and render it with a div content. It contains the HTML, jS and CSS combinations. When I formated this as html then the Js reference are not rendering. This is the problem I am seeing

Comment: @SivaRajagopal u need to load content from another js, html, css, am i right

Comment: @selva Yes ,dynamic references

Comment: Have you thought of rendering it in a partial view and then returning that from the controller?

Comment: @SivaRajagopal see this link http://api.jquery.com/load/, this what u r expecting i think so